# can't select item in dropdown

Tags: html, powershell, html-select

I have the following dropdown in html:

```
<select id="ctl00_MainContent_ddlPlatform" tabindex="1">
        <option selected="selected" value="-1">Please select...</option>
        <option value="4">UNIX</option>
        <option value="5">Database</option>
        <option value="6">Windows</option>
        <option value="8">AD Group</option>
        <option value="9">Network Devices</option>
</select>
```

In Poweshell I select it by id:

```
$serverType = $ie.document.getElementById('ctl00_MainContent_ddlPlatform')
```

get index for Windows:

```
$type = getValue $serverType.innerHTML 'Windows'
```

I checked, `$type = "6"`

and then select this option:

```
$serverType.Value = $type
```

But then I check `$serverType.Value`, it's empty.

It worked before, I didn't make any changes.

It's strange, but if I set

`$serverType.Value = "6"`, it's working.

**Update**:

and this is my function getValue:

```
function getValue($innerHTML, $serverName)
{   
    $position = $innerHTML.IndexOf($serverName)
    if ($position -ge 0)
    {
        $innerHTML = $innerHTML.Substring($innerHTML.IndexOf($serverName) - 11, 10)       
        return $innerHTML.Substring($innerHTML.IndexOf('=') + 1)
    }
    else
    {
        return -1
    }
}
```

what is also strange, if I try to cast `[int]$type`, I get error:

> Cannot convert value ""6"" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input
>   string was not in a correct format."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually $type was "6", but quotes marks were part of the string.

So I need to remove them, which I did by the following line:

```
$type.Replace("`"","")
```

Answer (score 0):

Set explicit string data type for **$type** variable:

```
[String]$type = getValue $serverType.innerHTML 'Windows'
```

Powershell set data type for new variable by its most appropriate type, in your case it was INT.

You can check variable data type like this:

```
PS C:\> $type = 6
$type.GetType().Name
Int32

PS C:\> $type = '6'
$type.GetType().Name
String
```

Comment: it doesn't help, anyway $serverType.Value is empty. And $type.GetType().Name is string in any case.